# How to make a logo resize properly in a responsive theme

Tags: theming

I am creating my first responsive website http://islamabadpools.com; I have used the Omega theme as a starter theme, and it works almost perfectly for the layout.

I used the absolute image module for adaptive images but it's not working for views banner slideshow.
I am also unable to make the logo responsive so I removed the logo from theme options.

I created a new article content, and added a logo as an image and given it a title logo; then, I created a view block with an article image field and filtered that with the title "logo"
and in field properties; in the view, I selected adaptive as the format.
Now my logo is responsive/adaptive but it's getting very small on lower screen sizes.

I repeated this for the quick assistance block displaying in the right corner of the header.

I just want to know what the right way to make the logo responsive is.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following css to your site:

```css
.view-logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```